# why k times differential of functional $u:U\to \mathbb{R}$ lies in $R^{n^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $u$ be a smooth functional $u:U\to \mathbb{R}$ ,with $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Why k times differential $D^k u$ can be identified as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^k}$.

For $Du$ I know how to do it that is $Du_x :T_xU\to \mathbb{R}$  hence $Du_x \in \text{Hom}(T_xU,\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.

I don't know how to show the result for higher order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is made apparent by looking at the second total derivative (the Hessian). To evaluate $D(Du_x)$ you need to specify a point $x_1\in T_xU\cong\mathbb{R}^n$ and a tangent vector $x_2\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed, the Hessian is defined as $H_x(x_1,x_2) = D(Du_x)_{x_1}(x_2)$, which is easily seen to be a bilinear map $H_x:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Taking another total derivative defines a trilinear ($3$-multilinear) map, and in general $D^ku: U\to L^k(\mathbb{R}^n\times\dotsm\times\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ associates to each $x\in U$ a $k$-multilinear map defined by the formula
$$(x_1,\dotsc, x_k)\mapsto D(D(\dotsm(Du_x)_{x_1})\dotsm)_{x_{k-2}})_{x_{k-1}}(x_k).$$

Now the problem reduces to proving that the dimension of $L^k(\mathbb{R}^n\times\dotsm\times\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ is $n^k$. To do this, fix a basis $e_1,\dotsc, e_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ . Then the set of $A_{j_1\dotsc j_k}:(\mathbb{R}^n)^k\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $A_{j_1\dotsc j_k}(e_{i_1},\dotsc, e_{i_k}) = \delta_{i_1j_1}\dotsm\delta_{i_kj_k}$ for $i_r,j_s\in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$ and $r,s\in\{1,\dotsc, k\}$ forms a basis for the set of $k$-multilinear maps; for each $j_s$ you choose from among $n$ options, and we do this $k$ times ($s=1,\dotsc, k$), so the dimension is $n^k$ as claimed.

Comment: thanks,I have two questions :(1)in the formula $H_x(x_1,x_2) = D(Du_x)_{x_1}(x_2)$ the outer $D$ acts on variable $x_1$ correct? (2) what's there difference of Hessian between $d\circ d$ ?We know for exterior derivative $d\circ d = 0$ but Hessian is not?

Comment: (1) $x_1$ is the point where the derivative is being evaluated for the outer $D$, while $x_2$ is the tangent vector we're feeding into the resulting linear map.

Comment: As for (2), the exterior derivative coincides with the (directional) derivative only for $0$-forms (functions). For something like $d(d\omega)$ the second $d$ actually has a different domain than the first $d$, since if $\omega$ is a k-form then $d\omega$ is a $k+1$ form. In this sense exterior differentiation is a "graded" map; we should have subscripts like $d_k$ and $d_{k+1}$ but we don't. It might be better to think of $d$ and higher order total derivatives as unrelated things (though one *can* express the Hessian as the covariant derivative of the exterior derivative).

Comment: thanks, very clear .

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the more general case of a smooth function $f : U \to \mathbb R^m$. Then $D_x f : T_x U \to T_{f(x)} \mathbb R^m$.

To get $D^2f$ it is not sufficient to separately consider the linear maps $D_x f: T_xU \to T_{f(x)} \mathbb R^m = \mathbb R^m$, $x \in U$, but the function $D f : TU \to \mathbb R^m, Tu(x,v) = D_xf(v))$, on the tangent bundle of $U$. We have $TU = U \times \mathbb R^n$, thus
$$D f : U \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m .$$
This can be identfied with
$$\hat D f : U \to \text{Hom}(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R ^m) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n \cdot m} , \hat D f (x) (v) = D_xf(v) .$$
Now you see that $D^2_x f : T_x U \to T_{f(x)} \mathbb{R}^{n \cdot m}  = \mathbb{R}^{n \cdot m}$. Iterating this yields
$$D^k_x f : T_x U \to \mathbb{R}^{n^k \cdot m} .$$

Comment: Thanks,I don't know why  $D^2_x f : T_x U \to T_{f(x)} \mathbb{R}^{n \cdot m}  = \mathbb{R}^{n \cdot m}$? since we use indentification $\hat{D}f$ in the inner one that is $D(\hat{D}f)_x$,why they are equal exactly?

Comment: Why not directly $D(Df)_x :T_xU\oplus T_?\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: In fact $D^2 f : TTU \to TT\mathbb R^m$. So technically you are right, $D^2_x f : T_xU \oplus T_0 \mathbb R^n = T_xU \oplus \mathbb R^n \to T_{f(x)}\mathbb R^m = \mathbb R^m$. But using $\text{Hom}$ allows to identify it with the map in my answer. But perhaps you tell us precisely how $D^2f$ is defined in the context of your question.

Comment: (I was reading PDE textbook,the definition of Hessian should be the one in classical analysis with $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ I just wonder whether we can generalize it to manifold.I don't know what is Hessian for differential geometric yet

Comment: I can learn it from Riemann geometry correct?

Comment: Yes - differential topology /differential geometry. Do you know the concept of tangential bundle?

Comment: Yes ,I know a little bit about it.